# Is the message.data tranfered only when code try get it?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

```js
let arr = [];
webworker.onmessage = function(mes){
  // arr.push(mes); fast
  arr.push(mes.data); // very slow
}
```

try get data from message run very slow.Does it is because the data transer run when code try get data?

Comment: I think it’s because when getting the `data` property, the data needs to be de-serialized every time, after being serialized when WebWorker communication happens.

Comment: Thank you!    yes, that is also my guess。the de-serialized not occur when onmessage function be called, but when the code try get `mes.data`.  The problem is I can not find any document for this, is there any officisal document.